# UK visit visa refusal; any possible solutions?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I have tickets for the Wimbledon final, scheduled on 15 July, obtained through the online ballot.
I am a government employee (since 28-6-2016), working as an assistant engineer with a net salary of 41000 INR.
I had been refused a visa, even after submitting bank statements (8 months), my Wimbledon ticket offer, pay slips (7 months), Form 16 for the last two years, NOC and leave sanction, appointment letter, accommodation proofs.
What are my chances if I apply again as the date of travel is closer?
Is it better if I opt for Premium Service? 
If you look at the refusal letter they have miscalculated the closing balance 3,75,000 is roughly 4175 pounds.I have paid for the wimbledon finals and received conformation i have provided all the evidence in support.I have a genuine reason but still refused..

[image]
[image]

Comment: Premium service will not increase your chances of success.  If you want to spend money to improve your chances, engage a British immigration lawyer.

Comment: Please don't use all capitals. Have a look at  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Comment: My edit was to remove the all caps, as it is considered shouting and a bit rude. Other note: after a refusal, your application would be pulled from the queue and not be given priority processing, and the monies for Premium would not be refunded.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to add an image of your refusal letter (with your personally identifying information redacted, of course.)

Comment: 41000INR (is that monthly?) is roughly £460, which is very little by UK standards. Do you have savings on top of that? Or by ‘net’ do you mean that figure is your monthly surplus of income over expenditure?

Comment: You need to address the "funds parking" issue of where that £3000 which appeared in your bank account came from, and justify how spending 3 months of your entire salary on a holiday makes sense. The ECO thinks that you can't in reality afford this trip and that it's just an excuse to try to move to the UK.

Comment: Take a look at this answer to a different question by Gayot Fow. Two bits from it: funds parking and possibly erratic/unstable lifestyle considering that £54 is fairly close to running to £0 or negative. https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/60899

Comment: @brhans that's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Also on the link I gave, take a look at "Proportionality". The whole paragraph suggests spending 2-3 months earnings is not proportional and not very likely to succeed. *Very* relevant to the 4th bullet point of your refusal letter that specifically mentions this.

Comment: Just as nobody seems to have said it: Applying closer to the travel date will not affect anything, especially not given the problems listed in the refusal.

Comment: @phoog - well - yes, but it's probably already covered (and in much better detail) in GayotFow's answer in the linked dup.

Comment: @brhans spending crazy money on a holiday is suspicious. When it's the final of a major sports event, lots of people would spend more than they can really afford!

Comment: @user16259 spending crazy money on holidays / major sport event was not the reason for refusal. The reason was that the OP appeared to want to spend crazy money that they don't have. If their balance was equally high (around 3K) for a few months as it is now, then it might have been approved.

Comment: @user16259 - all I'm doing is summarizing what the ECO wrote, not making a judgement. If the OP feels that's a valid argument then he should make it to the ECO.

Comment: A Wimbledon ballot ticket offer means nothing unless the purchase has been paid for. Centre Court tickets on finals day cost £210 http://www.britishtennis.com/tickets/wprices.shtml   Based on the OP’s stated income It looks like an attempt to fabricate a visit premise.

Comment: @brhans sorry, didn't intend to contradict you, just add a related point. Traveller has invalidated my point in their later comment in any case.